# selecting a specific columns to copy and paste?

Tags: excel, vba

i wrote a code in VBA to copy a selected columns from one worksheet to another.

```
For i = LBound(Accounts) To UBound(Accounts)
    For j = 1 To EndRowJE
        If Accounts(i) = shJE.Range("A" & j).Value Then
            shJE.Range("A" & j, "X" & j).Copy shReport.Range("A" & r, "X" & r)
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next j

Next i
```

i have an array full of values. i iterated through the array and check it against the first row the worksheet (shJE). if the array at i is the same as the cell in the shJE sheet then copy that row to the another sheet report. but i want to copy only specific columns not all the columns between A and X, instead i want to copy columns A, C, F and X. Any help is highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question but if you need only to copy

[Aj] to [Ar]

[Cj] to [Cr]

[Fj] to [Fr]

[Xj] to [Xr]

why don't you simply change you IF statement to :

```
If Accounts(i) = shJE.Range("A" & j).Value Then
            shJE.Range("A" & j).Copy shReport.Range("A" & r)
            shJE.Range("C" & j).Copy shReport.Range("C" & r)
            shJE.Range("F" & j).Copy shReport.Range("F" & r)
            shJE.Range("X" & j).Copy shReport.Range("X" & r)
            r = r + 1
End if
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i have also come up with the same approach, i thought if there is more efficient way. anyways thanks !

Answer (score 0):

nest outside the inner if loop another if loop that checks if its "A" || "C" || ...